# AutoMapper property name conversions

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to register a mapping convention to handle mapping from classes with Pascal Case names to classes with underscore names with postfix and prefix, and back again. I've tried to follow examples, but cannot get my head around how it's supposed to work.

This is one of the many things I've tried, that looks like it should work (in my opinion :)), but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
public class PascalCaseEntity
{
    public string CallingSystem { get; set; }
}

public class UnderscoreWithPrefixAndPostfixEntity
{
    public string p_calling_system_ { get; set; }
}

public class PartsMappings
{
    public void Apply()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<FromUnderscoreMapping>();
            cfg.AddProfile<ToUnderscoreMapping>();

            cfg.CreateMap<PascalCaseEntity, UnderscoreWithPrefixAndPostfixEntity>()
                  .WithProfile("ToUnderscoreMapping");
            cfg.CreateMap<UnderscoreWithPrefixAndPostfixEntity, PascalCaseEntity>()
                  .WithProfile("FromUnderscoreMapping");
        });
    }
}

public class FromUnderscoreMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        RecognizePrefixes("p_");
        RecognizePostfixes("_");
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "FromUnderscoreMapping"; }
    }
}

public class ToUnderscoreMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("p_");
        RecognizeDestinationPostfixes("_");
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "ToUnderscoreMapping"; }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution. I created two profiles, one for each "direction", and added the mappings to them.

I'm not too happy with it, since I'd rather have the mappings in the same file (grouping them on business area). But at least it works... :)

I also tried putting the registrations in the same Profile, and using the .WithProfile("ToUnderscoreWithPrefix") method, but I didn't get that to work.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new ToUnderscoreWithPrefixMappings());
    cfg.AddProfile(new FromUnderscoreWithPrefixMappings());
});

public class ToUnderscoreWithPrefixMappings : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("P", "p");

        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();

        CreateMap<PascalCaseEntity, UnderscoreWithPrefixAndPostfixEntity>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName { get; } = "ToUnderscoreWithPrefix";
}

public class FromUnderscoreWithPrefixMappings : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        RecognizePrefixes("P_", "p_");
        RecognizePostfixes("_");

        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();

        CreateMap<UnderscoreWithPrefixAndPostfixEntity, PascalCaseEntity>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName { get; } = "FromUnderscoreWithPrefix";
}
```